# How to detect that we are compiling for iOS simulator?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

Now that the iOS simulator is using ARM, how can we detect at compile time whether we are building the code for iOS or the iOS simulator? Is there a conditional define for this purpose?

Comment: Did you read the [Predefined Conditionals](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Conditional_compilation_(Delphi)#Predefined_Conditionals) documentation yet?

Comment: It appears you can use: IOSSIMULATOR. That table @RemyLebeau mentioned appears to have a bunch of issues.

Comment: Why read documentation before asking the question? Why not just ask the question without doing any research?

Comment: Incidentally, IOSSIMULATOR does not appear to be documented. but it appears throughout the source. It took a couple of minutes to verify that it applies to DCCIOSSIMARM64

Comment: Funny, I had already updated Indy awhile ago to use `IOSSIMULATOR`, I wonder where I got that from, if not the documentation.

Comment: sorry, I read the documentation before to ask but i didn't find anything in it regarding IOSSIMULATOR :( thanks @DaveNottage for your help

Comment: @zeus You would save yourself some trouble if you added some facts in the question. Like what kind of detection did you use previously and that documentation page (with link) does not have definition for simulator.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I don't know from where you got it, but there is no such thing in recent documentation. Also RTL code is full of various defines for simulator that include checking for X86 CPU and IOS. It is easy to miss IOSSIMULATOR define while searching code if you don't open each and every file where you can find word simulator.

Comment: A regex search of the source would answer this question. You know that you are searching for a conditional so that gives you `\$if` and you want a simulator so that's `simulator` so search for `\$if.*simulator`

Comment: @DavidHeffernan maybe but I don't see the problem to ask here to have a correct answer that can be used by all the community. At least this question point the fact that the documentation is incomplete ...

Comment: Questions like this are valuable, but so is learning how to search online and in the source code. A very large portion of my contributions on this site came about because I know how to use search and regex. I'm at the point where I think it is more important to show people how to find information themselves. That's better for everybody.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Just as side note, not all Delphi SKU have access to source code.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar Is it possible to get the mobile compilers with a SKU that doesn't have source code?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yes. Community Edition does not have source code and supports all platforms except Linux.